# JSP calling servlet and escaping annotations

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to call the RemoveKategorija servlet, send him the parameter "remove" + index od what he needs to remove from ArrayList, but I am having trouble with escaping the annotations.
Code:

```
<table border="1">
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>About</th>   </tr>         
            <% 
                for(Category k : Database.getCategory()){
            %>
                <tr><td> <%= k.getName() %> </td><td> <%= k.getAbout() %> </td><td><a href=\"RemoveCategory?remove=" + <%= Database.getCategory().indexOf(k) %> + "\"> remove</a></td></tr>
            <% } %>
</table>
```

Eclipse is showing errors:

Multiple annotations found at this line:

- Invalid location of text (?) in tag ().
- Invalid location of text (") in tag ().
- Undefined attribute name (RemoveCategory).
- Invalid location of text (\") in tag ().
- Undefined attribute name (remove).

Comment: try with this <a href ="/RemoveCategory?remove=<%=Database.getCategory().indexOf(k)%>">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possible answer to your query

```
 <a href ="/RemoveCategory?remove=<%=Database.getCategory().indexOf(k)%>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your `expression tag` within the quotes as :

```
<a href="RemoveCategory?remove=<%= Database.getCategory().indexOf(k) %>"> remove</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I didnt get it to work whith that piece of code, rather the one above...

Answer (score 1):

The Trick is Use Single quote in HTML Pages. In java use double quotes .. (Always helps differenciate the two) HTML= client side, Java/JSP = Server side

```
     <tr><td> <%= k.getName() %> </td><td> <%= k.getAbout() %> </td><td>
<a href='RemoveCategory?remove='<%= Database.getCategory().indexOf(k) %> > remove</a></td></tr>
```

and dont use + symobl to concatenate Scriptlet output in HTML . The scriptlet will just paste the data in the href.

This should work . I have typed and checked it in eclipse :)